# Getting a centre of an irregular shape

Tags: python, image-processing, opencv

I have a irregular shape like below:

[image]

I need to get the centre of that white area, I just tried with contour in openCV like below

```
img=cv.imread('mypic',0)
ret,thresh = cv.threshold(img,127,255,cv.THRESH_BINARY_INV)
cnts = cv.findContours(thresh.copy(), cv.RETR_EXTERNAL,
    cv.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
cnt = contours[0]
x,y,w,h = cv.boundingRect(cnt)
res_img = cv.rectangle(img,(x,y),(x+w,y+h),(0,255,0),2)
cv.imwrite('output.png',res_img)
```

But those cnts doeesn't give me very good results, as you can see the original image and its two small black point below the picture. Can someone point me to a good solution to get a centre of an irregular shape like above?

[image]

Comment: Apply some morphology to obtain a unique blob and compute central moments.You can calculate the center of mass using the zeroth and first moments.

Comment: I used some morphlogical transformation like dilation and erosion but there were no differences at all!

Comment: What does your contour look like?  As mentioned above by `@eldesgraciado`, compute the central moments to get the centroid point coordinates.  See https://learnopencv.com/find-center-of-blob-centroid-using-opencv-cpp-python/

Answer (score 4):

As I suggested, perform an `erosion` followed by `dilation` (an `opening` operation) on the binary image, then compute `central moments` and use this information to calculate the `centroid`. These are the steps:

1. Get a binary image from the input via **Otsu's Thresholding**
2. Compute **central moments** using `cv2.moments`
3. Compute the blob's **centroid** using the previous information

Let's see the code:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

# Set image path
path = "C:/opencvImages/"
fileName = "pn43H.png"

# Read Input image
inputImage = cv2.imread(path+fileName)

# Convert BGR to grayscale:
grayscaleImage = cv2.cvtColor(inputImage, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

# Threshold via Otsu + bias adjustment:
threshValue, binaryImage = cv2.threshold(grayscaleImage, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV+cv2.THRESH_OTSU)
```

This is the binary image you get. Notice the small noise:

[image]

The `opening` operation will get rid of the smalls blobs. A rectangular `structuring element` will suffice, let's use `3` iterations:

```
# Apply an erosion + dilation to get rid of small noise:

# Set kernel (structuring element) size:
kernelSize = 3

# Set operation iterations:
opIterations = 3

# Get the structuring element:
maxKernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (kernelSize, kernelSize))

# Perform closing:
openingImage = cv2.morphologyEx(binaryImage, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, maxKernel, None, None, opIterations, cv2.BORDER_REFLECT101)
```

This is the filtered image:

[image]

Now, compute the `central moments` and then the blob's `centroid`:

```
# Calculate the moments
imageMoments = cv2.moments(openingImage)

# Compute centroid
cx = int(imageMoments['m10']/imageMoments['m00'])
cy = int(imageMoments['m01']/imageMoments['m00'])

# Print the point:
print("Cx: "+str(cx))
print("Cy: "+str(cy))
```

Additionally, let's draw this point onto the binary image to check out the results:

```
# Draw centroid onto BGR image:
bgrImage = cv2.cvtColor(binaryImage, cv2.COLOR_GRAY2BGR)
bgrImage = cv2.line(bgrImage, (cx,cy), (cx,cy), (0,255,0), 10)
```

This is the result:

[image]

Answer (score 4):

One can think of the centroid calculated using the image moments as the "mass" center of the object in relation to the pixel intensity. Depending on the actual shape of the object it may not even be inside the object.
An alternative would be calculating the center of the bounding circle:

```
thresh = cv2.morphologyEx(thresh, cv2.MORPH_DILATE, np.ones((3, 3)))
contours, _ = cv2.findContours(thresh, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
contours = [c for c in contours if cv2.contourArea(c) > 100]
(x, y), r = cv2.minEnclosingCircle(contours[0])
output = thresh.copy()
cv2.circle(output, (int(x), int(y)), 3, (0, 0, 0), -1)
cv2.putText(output, f"{(int(x), int(y))}", (int(x-50), int(y-10)), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_PLAIN, 1, (0, 0, 0), 1)
cv2.circle(output, (int(x), int(y)), int(r), (255, 0, 0), 2)
```

The output of that code looks like this:
[image]

Answer (score 2):

You may want to try `ConnectedComponentsWithStats` function. This returns centroids, areas and bounding box parameters. Also blur and morphology(dilate/erode) helps a lot with noice, as noted above. If you're generous enough with erode, you`re gonna get almost no stray pixels after processing.